# Java encapsulation & array

Tags: java

Does returning  a copy of the contents of an array instead of a direct reference improve the encapsulation of a class?  I'm wondering if that is considered best practice.

Comment: I wouldn't even use an array, but yes, copying/cloning the array prevents other classes to manipulate your own array. But mind that the objects "in" that array aren't copied if you use a shallow clone. They still might be mutable.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to encapsulate a collection. If you provide a direct reference, there is no encapsulation for the collection. The user can do anything they want to the collection - even set it to null. If you are providing a deep copy of the collection to the user, then when they modify that copy, they are not modifying the collection in your class.

The best practice is to encapsulate the whole collection by never giving the user a reference to the collection. Instead, they will interface with it via the class methods. If they need to iterate over the whole collection, then it is best to return an Iterator over the collection, which will provide read-only access to it.

Say for example we have a class BookCollection, which has a private List as a data member. If we want consumers of the code to be able to add and remove books, etc., we will provide methods for them to do so.

Here is my example code:

```
public class BookCollection {
    private List<Book> books;

    public BookCollection() {
        this.books = new ArrayList();
    }

    public void addBook(Book book) {
        this.books.add(book);
    }

    public void removeBook(Book book) {
        this.books.remove(book);
    }

    public Book get(int index) {
        return this.books.get(index);
    }

    // etc.

    public Iterator<Book> getIterator() {
        return this.books.iterator();
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with this idea. You may also want to consider implementing the Iterable interface to support for-each on BookCollection.

Answer (score 0):

> Does returning a copy of the contents of an array instead of a direct
>   reference improve the encapsulation of a class? I'm wondering if that
>   is considered best practice.

*Data Hiding* is the practice of guarding the fields of your objects against access by other objects except as allowed and controlled by the programmer.  It would be much harder to encapsulate state within objects without data hiding.

Java has two broad categories of types of values: primitive types (which have only their values), and reference types (which have an identity that is separate from their values).

**Data Hiding and Primitive Types**

When you have an instance field that is immutable, an `int` for example, it is easier to maintain data hiding because returning the value of the `int` field provides no mechanism to users of your object to change its value.  In other words, when you return an immutable, primitive type to client code you do not need to worry about defensive copying.

```
public class MyClass {
    private int myField1;

    public MyClass(int initVal) { this.myField = initVal; }

    public int getValue() {
        return myField1;  // safe because ints are immutable, primitive types
    }
    :
    :
}
```

**Data Hiding and Reference Types**

Most types in Java, including many of the classes that programmers write themselves, are reference types (meaning that they contain an *identity* in addition to their values).  When programmers use variables for a reference type, that variable really contains an address to a location in memory where the instance of an object is located.  The variable of a reference type does not actually contain the value of the type.

Returning a reference type can allow users of your code to use the reference to access and change the fields of your objects, even if you didn't intend to allow them to (if the reference points to an object that is mutable).

```
public class MyClass2 {
    private int[] myField2;

    public MyClass2(int[] initVal) { this.myField = initVal; }

    public int[] getValue() {
        return myField2;  // not safe because int[] arrays are objects that
                          // are mutable reference types.  Anyone can use
                          // the returned reference to modify the array in
                          // your object.  The data is not hidden.
    }
    :
    :
}
```

When returning reference types to clients of your code, there are two ways to maintain data hiding and encapsulation:

- Return an immutable reference type.  Immutable objects can have one, and only one, state.  That state can't be changed, so even if you return the reference your data is still safe.
- Return a *defensive copy.*  Copy the data of the reference type into a new object, and return that to the user of your code.  Even if the user modifies the returned object, your own object will still remain intact.

To make the above example safe to return to clients of your API, we could simply create a copy of the array using the `clone()` method:

```
public class MyClass2 {
    private int[] myField2;

    public MyClass2(int[] initVal) { this.myField = initVal; }

    public int[] getValue() {
        return myField2.clone();  // now safe because we return a defensive
                                  // copy of our field.  Changes to the 
                                  // returned object won't affect this object.
    }
    :
    :
}
```

Defensive copying is one of the best practices to use to protect the integrity of your object's state.